# The If Else comparsion throws weired error

Tags: bash, syntax

Unable to run code, error `"[[Add:"` not found.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

add() {
    first="${1}"
    second="${2}"
    result=`expr $first + $second`
    echo  "The sum of two numbers are $result"  
    return $result
}


subtract() {
        first="${1}"
        second="${2}"
        result=`expr $first - $second`
        echo  "The sum of two numbers are $result"
    return $result 
}


echo "[0] Add"
echo  "[1] Subtract"

read operation

echo "Enter Number One"
read first
echo "Enter Number Two"
read second

if [["$operation" == "Add"]]
then
    add $first $second
else
    subtract $first $second
fi
```

I am trying to run this code, the if else comparison does not work. Each time i execute the code, at line 32 an error is occurred and else is executed. I am trying to create an addition/subtraction bash sh file.

```
root@Kumaraswamy:~# ./maths.sh
[0] Add
[1] Subtract
Add
Enter Number One
7
Enter Number Two
3
./maths.sh: line 32: [[Add: command not found
The sum of two numbers are 4
root@Kumaraswamy:~#
```

Comment: Paste your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/ and it's all become obvious

Comment: You need to leave a space around `[[` and `[`, burns everyone at the start: `if [[ "$operation"...`

Comment: Thank you! I did it as you told and it now works! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave a space after `[` or `[[`. That should work since these are real executables found in one of the directories listed under environment variable `$PATH`.

Comment: Actually, `[[` is a bash keyword, which allows it to have different syntax from what a regular command could have. But it's a key**word**, so (just like a command name) you can't attach something else to it.